# ngIf not reonize a variable value change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple variable boolean to show/hide a div, when I call the method to set the variable to true from another component the ngIf not recognize this.

my messages-refresh.component.html:

```
<div class="divOpacity" *ngIf="show">
<div class="boxMessageModal">
    <p>Novos dados foram encontrados para esta página, clique em Ok para atualizar!</p>
    <button class="btnOktoReload" (click)="reloadPage()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

my messages-refresh.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages-refresh',
  templateUrl: './messages-refresh.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages-refresh.component.css']
})

export class MessagesRefreshComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private location:Location) { }

  reloadPage(){
    location.reload(true)
  }

  show:boolean = false
  showDivOpacity(){
    this.show = true
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I call the method showDivOpacity in anothe component as `this.messagesRefreshComponent.showDivOpacity()`

Comment: Show the actual call. Maybe its made outside of the zone

Comment: @Diego 
in your second component can you put some console .log() statement to print the value of the show variable on the function call and post its result?

Comment: im simple inject the MessagesRefreshComponent and call this.messagesRefreshComponent.showDivOpacity()

Comment: @Vaibhav, the variable is showed in console as true, but the ngIf not show the div

Comment: I tyed call this.messagesRefreshComponent.show = true in the second component but have same problem

Comment: *im simple inject the MessagesRefreshComponent* you do what?? I bet you got different instances of the same component.

Comment: You better show that *injection* of yours

Comment: agreed with antoniossss @DiegoHillesheim kindly show the injection you have done

Comment: I import the component.ts, like this: import {MessagesRefreshComponent} from 'path'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have diferent instances because you are trying to use injection with a component.

You must try by using an injection class singleton with a BehaviorSubject this will provide just one instance with a storage to save an object or a value and get it in every components by injection

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
  private showSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  setUpdateShow(){
      this.showSobject.next(!showSobject.getValue());
  }

  isShowing$(){
     this.showSobject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

then in the components you will inject the value

**Component.ts that shows the subject**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages-refresh',
  templateUrl: './messages-refresh.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages-refresh.component.css']
})

export class MessagesRefreshComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private settingsService:SettingsService ) { }
 show$: Observable<boolean>()
 ngOnInit() {
   this.show$ = this.settingsService.isShowing$();
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divOpacity" *ngIf="show$ | async">
<div class="boxMessageModal">
    <p>Novos dados foram encontrados para esta página, clique em Ok para atualizar!   </p>
    <button class="btnOktoReload" (click)="reloadPage()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

To call or modify the subject you must inject the services and call the **setUpdateShow()** function I hope it helps you. It is a little bit hard to understand but its the best solution to comunicate components that aren't related between them.

Comment: Thank you, I will try do this!

Comment: to add `SettingsService` as singleton you need to add it in `app.module` as a `provider`

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' I have this error in this line  this.show$ = this.settingsService.isShowing$();

Comment: Add the returning type in the function  isShowing$(): Observable<boolean> {}

Comment: I just added :Observable<boolean> to isShowing$ and worked, tks